# Is there a term like n-ary that describes the number of return values instead of the number of parameters of a function?

Tags: parameters, arguments, return, tuples, return-value

I want to accept a function that returns a tuple. Is there a way to describe a function's return tuple length?

Comment: Well, the function in your case, would just return a single value, it is the tuple that is n-aray. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo a function is n-ary if it accepts n arguments, but I want to describe the number of return values instead of the number of parameters.

Comment: Well, my point is that your function will always return a value, what you need is name for the number of elements in a tuple, not for the number of elements being returned by the function. [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple), A 1‑tuple is called a singleton, a 2‑tuple is called an ordered pair and a 3‑tuple is a triple or triplet,..., and n-tuple is called, well, an n-tuple.

Comment: only way I know for multiple return values is to code in golang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doesn't seem to be. Probably because it isn't necessary in formal logic as 2 functions are used instead of one function with two outputs.
If the arity or adicity is the dimension of the domain of the cartesian product of a function what you are looking for is the dimension of the range.  Possibly the term "valency" could be used in a particular document as it has a similar meaning to arity but is not so commonly used in computer science so you could use it if you explained your usage up front.

Comment: univalent? bivalent? trivalent? tetravalent? ... plurivalent? (1, 2, 3, 4 ... n)

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics they'd call it an n-tuple. So a function returning list of 5 elements returns a 5-tuple.

(I've seen the term used in computer science too, and to people who already know what a tuple is, I think it's pretty clear what an n-tuple is, even if they've never seen the term before.)